# TypeScript Props as Array of Objects or string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I will receive a props `url` that could be string or array of objects like:

```
type VideoSrcProps = {
    url?: string;
    day?: string;
  };
  interface OwnProps {
    url: VideoSrcProps[] | string;
  }
```

But my implementation doesn't work because I receive
`Property 'url' does not exist on type 'string | VideoSrcProps' Property 'url' does not exist on type 'string'`

How it should be changed?

More code:

I'm checking that what will came array of string like

```
const srcIsArray = Array.isArray(url) ? true : false;
const notSingleArrayVideo = srcIsArray && url.length > 1 ? true : false;
```

And then

```
useEffect(() => {
    const preloadVideos = async () => {
      if (srcIsArray && notSingleArrayVideo) {
        const preloadedVideos = [];
        for (const video of url) {
          const response = await axios({
            url: video?.url,
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'blob',
          });
          const downloadedVideo = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
          preloadedVideos.push({ url: downloadedVideo });
        }

        if (preloadedVideos.length === url.length) {
          setPreloadedVideos(preloadedVideos);
        }
      }
    };
    if (srcIsArray && notSingleArrayVideo) {
      preloadVideos();
    }
  }, []);
```

The problem is with `url: video?.url`

Comment: where did you use those interfaces and types?  please add that code snippet also.

Comment: The ternary for `srcIsArray` may be preventing typescript from narrowing the type of `url`, try removing the ternary and I think typescript should narrow correctly? -  `const srcIsArray = Array.isArray(url)`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on this:

`const notSingleArrayVideo = srcIsArray && url.length > 1 ? true : false;`

TS will not narrow your type when using a stored value out of a [ternary](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37291).

You should use the condition directly in your `if` statement, or do an `if` and return.

```
type VideoSrcProps = {
    url?: string;
    day?: string;
  };


interface OwnProps {
  url: VideoSrcProps[] | string;
}


function test (url: OwnProps) {
  if (Array.isArray(url.url)) {
    for (const video of url.url) {
      console.log(video.url);
    }
  }
}
```